# Substituting factors for letters in expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have several large expressions that I'd like to substitute some factors for letter for the sake of simplicity. For example, I have this expression:

$$
\frac{C_3 C_5 (C_1+C_4)-C_1 C_6 (C_2+C_5)}{2 C_4 \sqrt{(C_1 C_6-C_3 C_4) (C_3 C_5-C_2 C_6)}}
$$

I would like to substitute the factor $(C_1C_6-C_3C_4)$ for $\kappa_1$ and $(C_3C_5-C_2C_6)$ for $\kappa_2$. What commands can I use to do this? I've tried using

```
expression /. {Subscript[C,1]*Subscript[C,6]-Subscript[C,3]*Subscript[C,4]-> Subscript[\[Kappa],1]}
```

for example, but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure how to find the several duplicates of this question, but the gist of the solutions are to choose one of those factors, say `C1` and make the replacement only for that term. This means that you would solve the replacement you have now to be in terms of only `C1` being replaced.

Comment: In order to understand why it does not work, please inspect `FullForm[expression]`